# SilverStripe check whether Controller action is called

Tags: php, silverstripe

Is there a way to check if a controller's action is called?

```
private static $url_handlers = array(
    '$Foo!' => 'Bar'
);

// action 'Bar' is allowed ...

public function Bar(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
    // method body
}

public function checkBar() {
    // Check if Bar is called
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use a `die('Bar called');` inside that action ? if it is executed, you will have a **Bar called** in your browser and the script will stop execution.

Comment: But what if he wants to peform other calls after that? He wont be able to because the script would have stopped... Iirc, you'll need a getter and setter for a boolean that you set to true in your `function bar` that you can call from `checkBar`

Comment: Correct, I don't want the code to stop executing. A setter/getter is a simple solution indeed. Still, I want to know if there is a built-in function in the framework.

Comment: Ah, I'm not sure. I'm not familiar with the silverstripe. but I can say it sounds like a complicated function to make. Best to just stick with a getter & setter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an aside to [WillParky93's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46299753/2812842), which will work for repeated action calls on a single controller instance, you can also use `Controller::getAction()` to check which action is being executed in the current request:

```
if ($this->getAction() === 'Bar') {
    // foo something
}
```

Or if you're expecting different instances of your controller to be called multiple times in the same request you could do what WillParky93 suggested, but use a static property instead so the state will persist over different instances.

Comment: So there is a built-in action after all

Comment: Okay so what is paradoxal about this, is that it always returns `NULL` when calling this in the controller's `Init` method. When called in the "active" controller method, it works and states the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, you can use a getter and setter with a boolean variable and check against it.

```
private static $url_handlers = array(
'$Foo!' => 'Bar'
);

 // action 'Bar' is allowed ...

private $barCalled = false;

public function setBar($value){
    $this->barCalled = $value;
}

public function Bar(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {
    if(!$this->barCalled){
        // method body
        $this->setBar(true);
    }
}


public function checkBar() {
    // Check if Bar is called
    return $this->barCalled;
}
```